# Duplicate Symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LoginController

Tags: ios5, linker, linker-errors, mach-o, duplicate-symbol

I know this Question has been asked many times before, but none has solved my problem uptill now. I know that this error occurs when you got multiple copies of your file in project.
I tried to clean the build, delete any *LoginController.m* file in *Compile Sources* and then build. Fine - no errors. When I added my LoginController.m file in Complie resources, compiler again gave the same error.

Next I what I tried is delete all .m files from Compile Sources, clean and rebuild successfully, and added each .m file very carefully. Again same error has been raised. I did not find any duplicate file, then why the heck is this happening?

Please someone guide me. Thanks alot.

**EDIT:**
Error is:

`Ld /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryAgain-dhbbyywxclvxfodbunqysmmfefcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TryAgain.app/TryAgain normal i386
    cd /Users/svp/Desktop/TryAgain
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryAgain-dhbbyywxclvxfodbunqysmmfefcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/svp/Desktop/TryAgain/TryAgain -L/Users/svp/Desktop/TryAgain/../CorePlot_1.0/Binaries/iOS -F/Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryAgain-dhbbyywxclvxfodbunqysmmfefcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryAgain-dhbbyywxclvxfodbunqysmmfefcl/Build/Intermediates/TryAgain.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TryAgain.build/Objects-normal/i386/TryAgain.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework MediaPlayer -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch -o /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryAgain-dhbbyywxclvxfodbunqysmmfefcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TryAgain.app/TryAgain`

`ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LoginController in /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryAgain-dhbbyywxclvxfodbunqysmmfefcl/Build/Intermediates/TryAgain.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TryAgain.build/Objects-normal/i386/LoginController.o and /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryAgain-dhbbyywxclvxfodbunqysmmfefcl/Build/Intermediates/TryAgain.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TryAgain.build/Objects-normal/i386/Navigator.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1`

Comment: Please show the whole linker error rather than trying to describe it.  It will usually have more information about how the symbol is being duplicated.

Comment: @PhillipMills I have mentioned the error.

Comment: Have you searched `LoginController` in the project files? It may be it's duplicated in a different file...

Comment: @madmw I have checked in project navigation as well as in finder that there are no two loginController files.

Comment: I mean searching as text in the project. It's not usual but it can happen.

Comment: Forget it, you'll get a compiler error before the linker does its thing.

Comment: I have also checked through text. there is only one file of .h and .m plus declared in a file for using it. Any other alternate?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your error message says that the binaries created from both LoginController.m and Navigator.m define an implementation for your `LoginController` class.  It sometimes happens that this is because of a shared header file that contains implementation logic.  Check your Navigator.h/.m for references to a `LoginController`.

Comment: Oh my God. Philips you really pointed out at the mistake. You are right. I declared "LoginController.m" instead of "LoginController.h" in a file - damn me. You really saved my time. You also helped me before. You rocks!! Thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome.  The "trick" in this case is to really focus on what the error message is trying to say.  That is, the symbol was found in both "LoginController.o" and "Navigator.o".  One of those is obviously expected but the other isn't.

Comment: This type of error is really hard to understand for beginners like me. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: thnx you saved my day :)