# Duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Base64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I am trying to add mobile.connect.framework to the existing project. Before adding the framework, The application is building and running properly. But, as soon as I am adding the framework, it is giving the Duplicate symbol *OBJC_CLASS*$_Base64  error. I went through numerous posts like [Duplicate Symbol *OBJC_CLASS*$_LoginController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541402/duplicate-symbol-objc-class-logincontroller)

and [How duplicate symbol problem arises](http://samwho.co.uk/blog/2013/12/08/duplicate-symbol-what//). But was unable to find the solution.
Please help me how to resolve this one. It has already consumed my half a day.

**Error** :-
`ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/shailendra.suriyal/Documents/MyProjects/..../UberNewUser/ExternalLib/CardIO' duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Base64 in: /Users/shailendra.suriyal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/./Build/Intermediates/Muri.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Muri.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Base64.o /Users/shailendra.suriyal/Documents/MyProjects/..../UberNewUser/ExternalLib/FrameWork/mobile.connect.framework/mobile.connect duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Base64 in: /Users/shailendra.suriyal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hadqxhhslzvmwfddwlthosrdljjy/Build/Intermediates/.../Debug-iphonesimulator/Muri.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Base64.o /Users/shailendra.suriyal/Documents/MyProjects/.../UberNewUser/ExternalLib/FrameWork/mobile.connect.framework/mobile.connect ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it. I just removed the Base64.h from the compiled resources under Build Phases.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be linking both the source and the library for the `Base64` class.

This line...
*/Users/shailendra.suriyal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Muri-hadqxhhslzvmwfddwlthosrdljjy/Build/Intermediates/Muri.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Muri.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Base64.o*
...says you've compiled the class directly.

This one...
   */Users/shailendra.suriyal/Documents/MyProjects/taxi_ios_client/UberNewUser/ExternalLib/FrameWork/mobile.connect.framework/mobile.connect*
...says you're linking it from inside the `mobile.connect.framework` binary.

If you're using it from the library, you should remove the source from your project.

(If you've already removed the source and you're still getting this, delete the derived data and try again.)

Answer (score 0):

DUPLICATE FILE CREATES OF "LoginController"